# Azure nodejs web app missing npm package in deployment

Tags: node.js, azure, npm, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

So, I am trying to deploy an Azure web app using Azure Pipelines from a git repo. The project is working fine locally, but when uploaded it says a package `is-docker` is missing (actually I get an ENOENT file or dir not found error). I am not using docker, and I guess Azure is trying to just check if I am, although **I have not installed this package.**

I am using node 10.x and npm 6.14 both locally and on azure. I am deploying an azure web app on Linux (ubuntu 20).

I would really appreciate some help.

**edit**
I added package is-docker to package.json but the problem still exists.

**edit 2**
Azure pipelines yml file.

```
# Node.js Express Web App to Linux on Azure
# Build a Node.js Express app and deploy it to Azure as a Linux web app.
# Add steps that analyze code, save build artifacts, deploy, and more:
# https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/languages/javascript

trigger:
  branches:
    - dev
    - master

variables:
  # Azure Resource Manager connection created during pipeline creation
  azureSubscription: 'XXXX'

  # Web app name
  webAppName: 'XXXX'

  # Environment name
  environmentName: 'XXXX'

  # Agent VM image name
  vmImageName: 'ubuntu-latest'

stages:
  - stage: Build
    displayName: Build stage
    jobs:
      - job: Build
        displayName: Build
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)

        steps:
          - task: NodeTool@0
            inputs:
              versionSpec: '10.x'
            displayName: 'Install Node.js'

          - script: |
              npm install
              npm run build --if-present
              npm run test --if-present
            displayName: 'npm install, build and test'

          - task: ArchiveFiles@2
            displayName: 'Archive files'
            inputs:
              rootFolderOrFile: '$(System.DefaultWorkingDirectory)'
              includeRootFolder: false
              archiveType: zip
              archiveFile: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
              replaceExistingArchive: true

          - upload: $(Build.ArtifactStagingDirectory)/$(Build.BuildId).zip
            artifact: drop

  - stage: Deploy
    displayName: Deploy stage
    dependsOn: Build
    condition: succeeded()
    jobs:
      - deployment: Deploy
        displayName: Deploy
        environment: $(environmentName)
        pool:
          vmImage: $(vmImageName)
        strategy:
          runOnce:
            deploy:
              steps:
                - task: AzureWebApp@1
                  displayName: 'XXXXXX'
                  inputs:
                    azureSubscription: $(azureSubscription)
                    appType: webAppLinux
                    appName: $(webAppName)
                    runtimeStack: 'NODE|10.10'
                    package: $(Pipeline.Workspace)/drop/$(Build.BuildId).zip
                    startUpCommand: 'npm run deploy'
```

The scripts in package json.

```
    "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\"",
    "start": "cross-env NODE_ENV=production node -r dotenv/config .",
    "dev": "ts-node-dev -r dotenv/config ./src/app.ts",
    "build": "tsc",
    "deploy": "tsc && cross-env NODE_ENV=production node -r dotenv/config ."
},
```

Error `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/is-docker'`

Comment: i dont have a specific answer unless you put the YAML file here. meanwhile, one of repos has a working YAML example for azure pipelines. give it a look here - https://github.com/Jay-study-nildana/ReactJSRecipeApp/blob/master/azure-pipelines.yml

Comment: why are you adding docker package if you are not using it. stop doing random things. the issue is elsewhere.

Comment: @Jay I knew this was not the case, I wanted to just check if another error would appear and search with the new error. I have created the pipeline with the classic editor and not yaml file, so I will upload some screenshots.

Comment: The classic editor is not recommended at all although it is still possible to use. you have got to upgrade to YAML as soon as possible. dont use the classic editor man. devops is about automation and those things happen better with commands and code.

Comment: Yeah, I m feeling that now. I' ll change that.

Comment: You know what, since I' ll be changing to yaml anyways, I might just do it now, and check if the error persists.

Comment: yeah. i was in the same boat as you. used classic editor for a long time but it got difficult and difficult as my project got complicated. ultimately i realized classic editor is meant for just learning the basics. for real work, YAML is the go to option. also, with classic editor, you have to keep putting screenshots which is slow and it may actually not be a good idea to show your project details like that.

Comment: exactly. i have put an example link about which you can use as a starting point. it is tested and works.

Comment: Still getting:
Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat '/home/site/wwwroot/node_modules/.bin/is-docker'

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/221688/discussion-between-jay-and-george-t).

Comment: Hi @GeorgeT, You can add the task Command line and enter the code cd "$(build.artifactStagingDirectory)" & dir /s /b, It should let you find the actual path to the zip file you're trying to publish. if the issue still occurs, please kindly share the log here. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help people. I just moved to Azure for Containers. I think I found the problem and had to do with the fact that I used many packages which had to do with complex libraries relevant to the host os (i am using windows and the other 3 members of my team are using Mac, and 2 different flavours of Linux) and the fact that Azure is not using the same image type everytime.

Anyways, the azure web app for containers seems a lot more stable and dockerhub is really easy and nice to have, so I do not have any problem for the time being. I was moving to containers anyways, so... how about you?

Comment: Hi @George T, Thanks for your sharing, you could accept your answer. In this case, others could directly find the useful solution.

Comment: @George T, since you switched to containers, did you have any issues that made you regret switching compared to Azure web apps?